# Wiki - File versioning

Tags: git, svn, version-control, version, wiki

I am building a wiki-like website, and am wondering how to implement the file versioning to create articles history. I would like to be able, when someone edits a file, to be able to display which parts were edited, and to revert back to a previous file if necessary.

EDIT:
Thank you for your responses. I started to go through them, and then I realized my post was not very precise. So I may add that I am using Java as a development language (Groovy through Grails to be precise). Also, the application I am building is not only a Wiki. It does plenty of other stuff but some parts should be editable by several users. So I am looking for the best candidate for that particular job.

Comment: may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406329/is-there-a-wiki-like-that-on-google-code-hosting-that-commits-every-change-in-th

Answer (score 2):

I would just look at how [ikiwiki](http://ikiwiki.info) or [gitit](http://gitit.net) are implemented (Perl and Haskell, respectively) as both are able to use Git as a backend.

As to ikiwiki (I'm using it for my intranet wiki at work) it saves page sources (wiki formatting) as plain files, and after each save (or `git push` from the outside) it "compiles" the site to a set of static pages.  It uses `make`-style approach for compiling the site though so ony the changed pages are rebuilt.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look at [Gollum](https://github.com/github/gollum), Github's git-powered wiki engine.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking of Git, what you need is already implemented in the forms of [`git blame`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-blame.html) and [`git checkout`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/how-do-i-reset-revert-a-specific-file-to-a-specific-revision-using-git).

Even though you *could* use those commands to get the job done, you would probably be better off with [`libgit2`](http://libgit2.github.com/) which is basically all the functionality you need, but as a library instead of executables.