# Is there a Wiki based on svn?

Tags: svn, sharepoint-2010, content-management-system, tortoisesvn, wiki

We are using TurtoiseSVN In our team as our Knowledge Base. Me manage our MS Office files in there (*.ppt, *.doc, *.xls ...).
For safety critical files we are using Sharepoint 2010.

Over the years we got a lot of "How-To" and organizational Powerpoint files. We would like to organize the information in these files in a wiki.

**The issue is:**

I'd like to avoid to launch a usual wiki.
Reasons: We don't want another system, since we already have so many in our company. Moreover the wiki won't be used that much, because you don't need the infos in there so often. So I would like to have it integrated in our running systems.

So I'm thinking about integrating the wiki into TortoiseSVN.

Question:
Is there any SVN based or file-system based wiki which can be integrated into SVN?
I already tried GrooWiki but I didn't get it working with TurtoiseSVN. Moreover it doesn't have a large community for support.

If there is not such a system, do you recommend to use the Sharepoint wiki?

While writing I get the feeling that I can't avoid to introduce a wiki like FosWiki as a third system:-(

Comment: Do you mean integration with TortoiseSVN, or just SVN? TortoiseSVN is just a client.

Comment: Have you checked [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/)? It is a lightweight Wiki + SVN server.

Comment: TortoiseSVN can integrate with issue trackers, see http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-bugtracker.html

Comment: If you already have Sharepoint, keep using it. It handles versioning and access control, and manages MS Office documents better than Subversion can.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate or related of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406329/ or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071810/ ; but for answers, also search for `[svn] [wiki]` in the search bar of stackoverflow for many related questions